# How do I reset the software Mac OS X Update Server

Tags: upgrade, restore, osx-server, services

I somehow managed to mis-configure my Mac OS X update-server and would like to reset it, the problem is that there is no reset button to put the update-server into it's original inactivated state.

So does someone here know how to reset the update-server completely without leaving traces from the configurations which have been done before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that that the question has been asked once in the superuser forum but I'm not sure if this method still works now with 10.6 Server. Can someone confirm if this method still works?

https://superuser.com/questions/85913/reset-os-x-software-update-server

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to control this from the Server Admin application. If it's not obvious from the UI or the help, add a comment here and I'll walk you through the UI steps.

Comment: Did you mean GUI->Servername/Settings/Service and then deactivate the softwareupdate Server?

Comment: That checkbox will allow Server Admin to administrate the service. You'll need to select it in the outline view on the left and then disable it from there.

Comment: But disabling the service will not reset the configurations and I ned to do a full reset of the Update Server